# I am Unable to display drop downlist using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my Project (ATM Tiller machine) I am trying to display a drop down list, but its displaying in grid format, because in my current project all dropdown displaying in grid/table format only, because these ddl are having very less records.
But I want i display dropdownlist with 100 records, so Table/Grid format is not possible, could you please help me how to display dropdown using MVC4.

```
XX.cshtml code:-
  var listBankNames = GetDropdownData(Model.AvailableBankList);
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bankname.Value, listBankNames, "", null)
```

At present result is showing as Grid format, But I need dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bootstrap** in your project, then add a class to your dropdown like bellow,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bankname.Value, listBankNames, 
       "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control dropdownlist" })
```

Or else add a class to your dropdown and override the style in CSS,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bankname.Value, listBankNames, 
       "--Select--", new { @class = "myDropdown" })
```

In your CSS,

```
.myDropdown
  {
   display: inline-block !important;
   position: absolute !important;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   padding: 12px 16px;
   z-index: 1;
  }
```